# i want to hide the login button and registeration while i am logged in

Tags: php

I'm kinda new in PHP and I have some issues. When I'm logged in on my website I want to hide the 'Login' and 'Register' button, and when I'm logged out I want to hide the 'logout' button.

This is my login.php page:

```
<?php
include('func/conn.php');

$logout = "";
$add_product = "";

if(isset($_SESSION['logged_id']))
{

    $logout = "<li><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a></li>";

    if($_SESSION['user_access'] == 'Seller')
    {
        $add_product = "<li><a href='add_product.php'>Add Product</a></li>"; 



    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use logic:

```
<?php
      if(isset($_SESSION['logged_id'])) {
?>    
         <li><a href='<?=logout.php?>'>Logout</a></li>
<?php   
      }else{
?>
         <li><a href='<?=login.php?>'>Login</a></li>
         <li><a href='<?=registration.php?>'>Registration</a></li>
<?php   
      }
?>
```

Make changes as per your code requirement.. its just for reference